# RxJS distinct on array of objects in property

Tags: rxjs

i am having an observable which returns something like this:

```
"@odata.context": "here is the context URL",
"value": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Value": "A"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Value": "B"
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "Value": "C"
        },
        {
            "Id": 4,
            "Value": "A"
        }
    ]
}
```

Using RxJS i would like to get into the "value" property and use distinct on it to limit the response to something like this:

```
"@odata.context": "here is the context URL",
"value": [
        {
            "Id": 1,
            "Value": "A"
        },
        {
            "Id": 2,
            "Value": "B"
        },
        {
            "Id": 3,
            "Value": "C"
        }
    ]
}
```

could you help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It pretty much depends on how exactly you want to use this RxJS chain but I hope this leads you the right direction:

```
const source = of(data)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(d => d.value),
    distinct(v => v.Value),
    toArray(),
  )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

`mergeMap` will reiterate the array of values as separate emissions where `distinct` will ignore duplicate `Value`s. Then `toArray()` will just collect all results.

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-is1zp4